# Get a database reference in the new Firebase 4.0 release

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase 3.0+ the method to get the database reference was as such:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


ref.child("rooms").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.hasChild("room1"){

        print("true rooms exist")

    }else{

        print("false room doesn't exist")
    }

})
```

In Firebase 4.0 the naming convention changed but I can't get it to work!?

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!    
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

The swift compiler is suggesting removing the () from the lowercase database function call

if you remove it, it then throws the error message:

- Database has no member reference

So how do you get the reference then!?

Pod file:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the update code, perhaps the compiler hasn't done a good job of suggesting a fix

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()  

ref.child("rooms").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  // ...

  })
```

as you can see, the code works perfectly, consider `pod deintegrate` & `pod update`

[image]

Comment: its failing at : ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()  I makes no difference what the rest of the code does when its fails at setting the init reference!?

Comment: did you declare `ref` before?

Comment: @iosforme, what error are you hitting?, try using my above code and see if it would work, besides your implementation... just to narrow the issue down

Comment: its in the question, first it suggests to remove the () when u do it says that database has no member called reference

Comment: var ref: DatabaseReference!    
ref = Database.database().reference()

Comment: the FIR... naming convention has been removed, i was putting that as it worked prior to 4.0 release

Comment: @iosforme, hmmm, everything seems in order to be honest... I went through the code I use and the documentation and everything seems alright. Try `pod deintegrate`, `pod install`

Comment: I ran the pod reintegrate and install and the same thing occurred

Comment: this is nuts... I have the same thing as you and its erring out on me!? I ran the pod commands you provided as well started a new project instance and the same error occurs !? WTF!!!!

Comment: @iosforme did you try deleting the derived Data folder?

Comment: i ran this: rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods; rm -rf Pods; rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*; pod deintegrate; pod setup; pod install;

Answer (score 1):

The firebase documentation needs to be updated.
1. import both of these at the top of your class

```
import FirebaseCore

import FirebaseDatabase
```

2. Getting a DB reference only works within ViewDidLoad()

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
super.viewDidLoad()
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems right to me (for the [new Firebase 4](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)):

```swift
var ref: DatabaseReference!    
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

And, looking at [their source code (`FIRDatabase.h`)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Database/Api/FIRDatabase.h), everything you are doing matches *perfectly*:

```c
FIR_SWIFT_NAME(Database)
@interface FIRDatabase : NSObject

+ (FIRDatabase *) database FIR_SWIFT_NAME(database());

- (FIRDatabaseReference *) reference;
```

Are you sure you are on their latest SDK version? As a last resort, try this:

```sh
pod cache clean
rm Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods
pod install
rm -rf DerivedData
```

Comment: Its states firebase (4.0.0) after the pod install

Comment: I added the extract from my podfile

Comment: BTW the reason it suggests to remove the () on the Database.database() is due to the error cannot call value of non-function 'Database'

Comment: Has anyone actually upgraded to the new Firebase 4.0 and seen the issues or am i the only one right now!?

Comment: ...me neither, looks like you are the only one bro ;)

Comment: I ran the updated pod commands, they all executed perfectly an nothing, same error!?

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase 4.0, there is a change

- Removing the FIR prefix across names for all constants, protocols,
  classes, enums, and type definitions.
- Renaming FIRApp to FirebaseApp.
- Renaming FIROptions to FirebaseOptions.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide